# Why are "lock" files used in PHP instead of just counting the processes?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, daemon

I've seen a lot of examples where a "lock" file is used to keep track of if a PHP script is currently running.

Example:

1. script starts
2. checks if "/tmp/lockfile" is currently locked
3. If it is locked, exit. If not, lock the file and continue

This way, if a long-running script is started up twice, only the first instance will run. Which is great.

However, it seems like the wrong way to go around it. Why don't we just check if the process is already running like this?

```
if(exec("ps -C " . basename(__FILE__) . " --no-headers | wc -l") > 1){
  echo "Already running.";
  exit;
}
```

Are there any potential pitfalls to this method? Why do I see the "lock" file workaround so often? It definitely seems more accurate to count the processes with the name we're looking for....

Comment: Probably because checking the lock file can be done in pure PHP without knowledge of Bash etc...

Comment: depending on your hosting you might not have the ability to run exec

Comment: I think you might consider editing your question... this definitely applies to general practice that is more broad than PHP.

Comment: @Brad - Good point. It could apply in other contexts as well. However, I was partially wondering if there were any pitfalls to this method that were PHP specific.

Comment: because `ps` works only in linux, flock works on windows too

Comment: Yes, Bash isn't supported on many Windows servers

Comment: The best way to implement something like this, is to create your own script based locking system if you want 100% cross system compatibility because php(s) implementation of flock is not guaranteed to work on all operating systems, (multi threaded servers)... that's what drives me batty about php sometimes, I mean it has something like 6,000 core functions, but it still has major problems controlling simple system level access calls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments here and my own observations, I've composed a list of pro's and con's of both approaches:

### `flock` method:

pros:

- More compatible across operating systems
- No knowledge of bash required
- More common approach, lots of examples
- Works even with `exec()` disabled
- Can use multiple locks in a single file to allow different running "modes" of the same file at the same time

cons:

- It's not definite. If your lock file is deleted by an external process / user, you could end up with multiple processes. If you're saving the lock file in the `/tmp` directory, that's a valid possibility, since everything in this directory is supposed to be "temporary"
- Under certain circumstances, when a process dies unexpectedly, the file lock can be transferred to an unrelated process (I didn't believe this at first, but I found instances of it happening (although rarely) across 200+ unix based systems, in 3 different operating systems)

### `exec("ps -C...")` method

pros:

- Since you're **actually counting the processes**, it will work everytime, regardless of the state of file locks, etc.

cons:

- Only works in linux
- requires "exec" to be enabled
- If you change the name of your script, it could cause double processes (and make sure your script name isn't hard-coded in the code)
- Assumes that your script only has one running "mode"

---

EDIT: I ended up using this:

```
if (exec("pgrep -x " . $scriptName . " -u ". $currentUser . " | wc -l") > 1)
{
  echo $scriptName . " is already running.\n";
  exit;
}
```

... because `ps` doesn't allow you to filter on the owner of the process in addition to the process name, and I wanted to allow this script to run multiple times if a different user was running it.

---

EDIT 2:

... So, after having that running for a few days, it's not perfect either. Somehow, the process started up multiple times on the same machine under the same user. My only guess is that there was some issue (ran out of memory, etc) that caused the `pgrep` to return nothing, when it should have returned something.

So that means that NEITHER the `flock` method and the counting process methods are 100% reliable. You'll have to determine what approach will work better for your project.

Ultimately, I'm using another solution that stores the PID of the current task in a "lock" file, that's not actually locked with flock. Then, when the script starts up, checks if the lock file exists, and if it does, gets the contents (PID of the last time the script started up) Then, it checks if it's still running, by comparing the `/proc/#PID#/cmdline` contents with the name of the script that's running.

Comment: con of this exec method: it assumes the script is used for only this function.  If your script has two or more functions it might be another one running.  One can of course argue than each function should be in its own file.

Answer (score 1):

The most important reasons that lock files are used, unfortunately not given in the other answers, is that lock files use **a locking mechanism that is atomic**, allow you to run **multiple instances your script**, at a higher level context than the script itself, and **are more secure**.

#### Lock files are atomic

Iterating through a process list is inherently prone to race conditions; in the time it takes to retrieve and iterate through the list a second process might have just spawned, and you unintentionally end up with multiple processes.

The file locking mechanism is strictly atomic. Only one process can get an exclusive lock to a file, so when it does have a lock, there is no possibility the same command will be running twice.

#### Lock files allow for multiple instances of the same script

Say you want to have several separate instances of a script running, but each with its own scope/options. If you'd simply count the number of times the script appears in ps output, you'd only be able to run a single instance. By using separate lock files you can properly lock its running state in an individual scope.

#### Lock files are more secure

Lock files are simply a much more elegant and secure design. Instead of abusing a process list (which requires a lot more permissions and would have to be accessed and parsed differently on each OS) to deduce if a script is already running, you have a single dedicated system to explicitly lock a state.

### Summary

So to reiterate all the reasons lock files are used over other methods:

- Lock files allow for **atomic locking**, negating race conditions.
- They allow for running **multiple instances**/scopes of the same script.
- File system access is more **universally available** than execute permissions or full access to process information.
- They are more **secure**, because no permissions outside of the specific lock file are needed.
- Using file locks is more **compatible** across different operating systems.
- It is a more **elegant** solution; doesn't require parsing through a process list.

As for the cons mentioned in other answers; that the lock file can be deleted and sometimes the lock is transferred to another process:

Deletion of lock files is prevent by setting proper permissions, and storing the file on non-volatile storage. Lock files are "definite" if used according to spec, unlike a process list.

It's true a process that forks a child process wil "bequeath" it's lock to any child processes that are still running, however this is easily remedied by specifically unlocking the file once the script is done. E.g. using `flock --unlock`.

Long story short: ***you should always use lock files over parsing running processes***.

#### Other solutions

There are other solutions, though they usually offer no benefit over simple file locks unless you have additional requirements:

- Mutexes in a separate database / store (e.g. redis).
- Exclusively listening to a port on a network interface.

Answer (score 0):

First, the command is not right . When I run `php test.php` and the command

```sh
 ps -C test.php
```

whill get nothing. You can use `ps -aux|grep 'test.php' -c` to get process number.But `exec("ps -aux|grep 'php test.php' -c");` return number must minus 2 is the real process number

The reason to use lock file most reason is exec or other command function need some special permission, and is disable_functions in php.ini default config.

Test script like this:

```php
$count = exec("ps -aux|grep 'php test.php' -c");

if($count > 3){
  echo "Already running.".$count;
  exit;
}

while(1){
    sleep(20);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, you may have something wrong with your `ps`? According to the [manual](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ps1.html), `-C` is "Select by command name." For me, the bash command in my code returns "1" while the process is running. Also, `-C` requires an exact match, your `grep` will also get partial matches, which could mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why "lock files" are used is simply because they can be expected to work in *any* host-environment.  If you can "create a file," and if you can "lock it," such code will work ... anywhere.

Also – "there is nothing to be *gained* by being 'clever.'"  This well-known strategy is known to work well – therefore, "run with it."

Comment: The "lock" file method was working great for me - until I started using it in 200+ locations on a few scripts. I started noticing strange things happening (like unrelated scripts (rarely) "stealing" the lock on the file, preventing it from working properly. Maybe an OS issue with file locks?)

Anyway, my scripts only run on Linux (and that won't change). So in my case, a solution that absolutely works regardless of file lock states is better than a solution that works in any host-environment.

Comment: A critical problem with "lock files" in some operating systems e.g. Unix/Linux is that locks are considered _advisory._  Often, therefore, the **presence of** the file is used as an indication of a lock being in place.

Comment: I've seen a "presence of file" implementation before. My only concern with that one (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that if the process suffers a "hard" crash, the file will we left behind, and the script will no longer be able to self-recover (since it thinks it's still running)